# Having problems while uploading images in Opencart 1.5.6.4

Tags: opencart

Whenever I try to upload an image to my Opencart 1.5.6.4 website the pop-up menu duplicates the sign in page of the Opencart itself, thus not letting me upload. Please help, I have been looking for solutions for hours. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Have you changed any file in the controller?

Comment: @Ziauz No, I didn't

Comment: @Ignacio Ara but there is, unfortunately, no coding involved, and I don't have enough points to upload images of what is going on.

Comment: You can use services like imgur for images

Comment: sounds like either your session has expired or your config file is pointing to the wrong place.

Comment: @billynoah the session has not expired but the config file might be pointing to the wrong place indeed.